# How to manipulate the alignment of members in aggregate types?

Tags: c++

Given two simple aggregate types:

```
template <class scalar_t>
struct vec3 {
    constexpr static auto size = 3;
    scalar_t x, y, z;
    // ctor, assign, dtor omitted for brevity
};

template <class scalar_t>
struct vec2 {
    constexpr static auto size = 2;
    scalar_t x, y;
    // ctor, assign, dtor omitted for brevity
};
```

I'd like to compose other aggregate types, which hold conditional members of the above standing `vecN` types. If the conditional is met, a `vecN` is used, else an `empty_t` is used. Here is a possible `empty_t` definition:

```
struct empty {
    constexpr static auto size = 0;
};

using empty_t = empty; // or std::monostate from <variant>
```

I now want to compose different `vertex` types; with different combinations of `position_type`, `color_type` and `texture_coord_type`:

```
template <bool has_color = false, bool has_texture = false>
struct vertex {
    using position_type = vec3<double>;
    using color_type = std::conditional_t<has_color, vec3<double>, empty_t>;
    using texture_coords_type = std::conditional_t<has_texture, vec2<double>, empty_t>;
    
    position_type position{};
    color_type color{};
    texture_coords_type texture_coords{};
    // ctor, assign, dtor omitted for brevity
};
```

A `vertex` type only containing positional data can now be declared as:

```
    using p_vertex = vertex<false, false>;
```

The issue now lies within the compiler generated alignment of the resulting type; unfortunately the `empty_t` still requires `1 Byte`, which I am not certain why that is needed.

```
    std::cout << "position vertex:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(p_vertex::position_type{}) << std::endl;          // 24
    std::cout << sizeof(p_vertex::color_type{}) << std::endl;             // 1
    std::cout << sizeof(p_vertex::texture_coords_type{}) << std::endl;    // 1
    std::cout << sizeof(p_vertex{}) << std::endl << std::endl;            // 32
```

Therefore the entire type is padded to align with 32 bytes.

**Questions:**

1. <strike>Is there a way to force 24 bytes alignment with `sizeof(empty_t) == 0` somehow?</strike>
   [**Answered** by @Michaël Roy: No. If the members exists, it must have an address of at least 1 Byte.]

   - with [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) or [alignof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) ?
   - <strike>with `struct vertex : public std::conditional_t<has_color, mixin_color, empty_t>` inheritance?</strike> 
     [**Answered**: Yes, but the members do not exist; just their types: https://godbolt.org/z/he3q1W7rY]
2. Assume that each `vecN`'s `scalar_t` is separately templated in this manner:

```
   using position_type = vec3<A>;
   using color_type = std::conditional_t<has_color, vec3<B>, empty_t>;
   using texture_coords_type = std::conditional_t<has_texture, vec2<C>, empty_t>;
```

Is there a way to force non-padded alignment for the resulting types? In this example `A`, `B` and `C` can be assumed to always be a `builtin integral` from `<cstdint>` (e.g. `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, etc.) or `float`/ `double` (not `complex`). A second Godbolt example for this question can be found below.

**Godbolt Examples**:

- Question 1: <strike>https://godbolt.org/z/fGzoaePrT</strike> [Answered: https://godbolt.org/z/he3q1W7rY]
- Question 2: https://godbolt.org/z/1PYWss3ra

Comment: there is empty base class optimization, so your second bullet might be a way to go. did you try it?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not manage to get a working example for that one. It always resulted in a empty `1 Byte` alignment.

Comment: From what I understand, empty_t (as all emprty types) requires 1 byte so that it has an address.

Comment: just to understand, you want the members to be present but conditionally not taking any space. Conditionally removing the member is not what you want. A instantiation of `vertex ` should always have a `color` member. right?

Comment: indeed. "1 Byte, which I am not certain why that is needed." because it has an address. There is no such thing as a "empty member optimization". A member has an address.

Comment: I read too fast, my bad.

Comment: "From what I understand, empty_t (as all emprty types) requires 1 byte so that it has an address. "  


Ty @MichaëlRoy and 463035818_is_not_a_number. That makes sense.  


"A instantiation of vertex  should always have a color member. right? "   



According to the previous comments - this should not be possible, if the member is existent. I am content, if the member does not exists, as long as I can probe color_type::size for example (which should be 0 if its empty_t). 

This is what I have right now: https://godbolt.org/z/3WoqhjMq4 (work in progress)

Comment: sorry not sure if the answer to "The member must be present always?" is yes or no

Comment: The member must not always be present. Its type must be present. This here is a solution: https://godbolt.org/z/he3q1W7rY Question 1 is answered. Only Question 2 remains open. I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: EBO is guaranteed only for single inheritance, not multiple inheritance (especially msvc only apply EBO to last class).

Comment: In the same non guarantee, there is [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) in C++20.